# I can not exit Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

As you can see in the screenshot below, there isn't an "Exit DF" choice, so how can I exit DF?

[image]

Comment: Well that's a cool approach to make an addictive game -- make a game from which you cannot exit! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press the up arrow key once. Or press down 6 times. (The menu scrolls if there are more than 6 options!

Comment: D'oh! Why didn't I think of that?